Unable to Fetch Conversations in React App Using Axios - tokens not being sent correctly in GET request
I'm working on a React app where I am expecting to fetch a list of conversations for the logged-in user. This has been achieved already with Postman on the production API.
However, in the API-connected front-end, the GET request to fetch conversations is not executing properly. I have documented in my code where tests are failing, particularly in the MessageList component, where the access tokens don't appear to be fetched correctly. I've learnt that the token might not be sent correctly or is invalid.
relevant files

AxiosDefaults

// src/api/axiosDefaults.js

import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://odyssey-api-f3455553b29d.herokuapp.com/";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export const axiosReq = axios.create();
export const axiosRes = axios.create();


CurrentUserContext

This appears to enable to login the user succesfully
// src/contexts/CurrentUserContext.js

import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { axiosReq, axiosRes } from "../api/axiosDefaults";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import { removeTokenTimestamp, shouldRefreshToken } from "../utils/utils";

export const CurrentUserContext = createContext();
export const SetCurrentUserContext = createContext();

export const useCurrentUser = () => useContext(CurrentUserContext);
export const useSetCurrentUser = () => useContext(SetCurrentUserContext);

export const CurrentUserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleMount = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axiosRes.get("dj-rest-auth/user/");
      setCurrentUser(data);
      console.log('Current user data:', data); // PASS. Current user data: { pk: 13, username: "user1", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: "", ... }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch current user data:', err); // Not registering
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleMount();
  }, []);

  useMemo(() => {
    axiosReq.interceptors.request.use(
      async (config) => {
        if (shouldRefreshToken()) {
          try {
            const response = await axios.post("/dj-rest-auth/token/refresh/");
            console.log('Token refreshed:', response.data); // PASS. Token refreshed: { access: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...', ... }
          } catch (err) {
            setCurrentUser((prevCurrentUser) => {
              if (prevCurrentUser) {
                history.push("/signin");
              }
              return null;
            });
            removeTokenTimestamp();
            return config;
          }
        }
        return config;
      },
      (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    );

    axiosRes.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response,
      async (err) => {
        if (err.response?.status === 401) {
          try {
            const response = await axios.post("/dj-rest-auth/token/refresh/");
            console.log('Token refreshed after 401:', response.data); // Token refreshed after 401: { access: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...', ... }
          } catch (err) {
            setCurrentUser((prevCurrentUser) => {
              if (prevCurrentUser) {
                history.push("/signin");
              }
              return null;
            });
            removeTokenTimestamp();
          }
          return axios(err.config);
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    );
  }, [history]);

  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider value={currentUser}>
      <SetCurrentUserContext.Provider value={setCurrentUser}>
        {children}
      </SetCurrentUserContext.Provider>
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
};


MessageList

trying to call this array from GET https://odyssey-api-f3455553b29d.herokuapp.com/conversations/?Authorization=eyJ0eXAiOiJ....
to retrive
[{"id": 15,"username": "user3" }, {"id": 14,"username": "user2"},{"id": 16,"username": "user4"}]
The above was retrieved successfully as a GET request with Postman API handler after POST login details https://odyssey-api-f3455553b29d.herokuapp.com/dj-rest-auth/login/
with body: {"username": "user1","password": "*****"}
note the console.logs that are NOT registering.
// pages/messaging/MessageList.js


import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { axiosReq } from '../../api/axiosDefaults';
import { CurrentUserContext } from '../../contexts/CurrentUserContext';

const MessageList = () => {
  const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
  const { currentUser } = useContext(CurrentUserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchConversations = async () => {
      if (!currentUser || !currentUser.token) {
        console.error('Token is missing or current user is not set'); // Not registering
        return;
      }

      console.log('Current user (MessageList):', currentUser); // FAIL. Not registering
      console.log('Current user token (MessageList):', currentUser.token); // FAIL. Not registering

      try {
        const response = await axiosReq.get('/conversations/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${currentUser.token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Specify Content-Type for this request
          },
        });
        console.log('Fetched conversations:', response.data); // FAIL. Not registering
        setConversations(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch conversations:', error); // FAIL. Not registering
      }
    };

    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
      console.log('Fetching conversations...'); // FAIL. Not registering
      fetchConversations();
    } else {
      console.log('Current user or token is missing:', currentUser); // Current user or token is missing: undefined
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  console.log('Conversations state:', conversations); // Conversations state: []

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Conversations</h1>
      <ul>
        {conversations.length > 0 ? (
          conversations.map((conversation) => (
            <li key={conversation.id}>{conversation.username}</li>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No conversations found.</p>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MessageList;



Debugging Steps Taken

Verified that the GET request URL is correct and matches the successful Postman request.

Verified that tokens are being retrieved successfully after login using Postman:
[{"id": 15,"username": "user3" }, {"id": 14,"username": "user2"},{"id": 16,"username": "user4"}]

Added extensive console logs to check if the current user and token are being set correctly:

Current user data logged correctly in  console.log('Current user data:', data); // Current user data: { pk: 13, username: "user1", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: "", ... }

Current user data logged correctly in MessageList

console.log ('Current user:', currentUser); // Current user: Object { pk: 13, username: "user1", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: "", ... }
console.log('Current user token:', currentUser.token); // Token refreshed: { access: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...', ... }


tried setting the Content-Type header to application/json for the GET request.


Observations

The 401 Unauthorized error suggests that the token might not be sent correctly or is invalid.
Despite logging in and getting tokens, the request to fetch conversations is not being executed properly. The console logs in the MessageList component are not registering the fetched data.
Nework tab in Devtools shows that the GET request is being made with the correct token. 

Resources:
github.com/lmcrean/odyssey-react

Where's the /conversations on your network logs?
Not seeing it going through.

When I use axios with a baseUrl I import it from a helper file, instead of from the base module. For instance, try import {axiosRequest as axios} from "./src/api/axiosDefaults.js" and use that as your caller.
Otherwise, there's a chance your default settings aren't being brought over.

leads to terminal error
./src/pages/messaging/MessageList.js Module not found: Can't resolve './src/api/axiosDefaults.js' in '/workspace/moments-clone-2/src/pages/messaging'

Double check my path. I'm not sure how you have your files structured.
May need to be ../api/axiosDefaults.js" or just src/ (if it's the js base)
